# Any tools to monitor the changes made by an application?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, monitor

I want to monitor the changes made by my installer, and I found the processmonitor is useful, But it just get too many information, and really hard to retrieve what I need. Is there any better solution on monitoring ?  Like what folder, file, registry the application created ?

Thanks !

Comment: nope, ProcessMonitor is pretty much the best tool. Judicious use of filters recommnded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often used InCtrl 5 (it's old but usefull).

Answer (score 0):

did you try filtering un-necessary information? 
Filters in processmon are very good and correctly prints only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for professional application, there was one I used to use: Norton Cleansweep.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_CleanSweep

Its no longer developed by Norton, but should not be hard to find if you want to grab one copy.